# Add registration form during checkout

Tags: magento2, php, onepage-checkout

Magento provides a registration step at checkout only if Guest checkout is disabled.

Is there a way to show the registration form with Guest checkout enabled?

Answer (score 0):

Magento provides a way to register even if guest checkout is enabled.
After filling in your email address you should see a message saying you can create an account after placing an order

[image]

If you don't like this approach, you will need a lot of changes. I don't have a fully working code, but here are some ideas to start

Create one additional checkbox in the checkout below the email address field saying "Create an account" This checkbox should be visible only if the email address does not exist in the system. (magento does a check to see if the email exists).
When the user checks this checkbox, 2 extra fields should appear (password and retype password).
You will also need to remamber during the checkout process if the checkbox was checked. IN this case you need a pluging or observer that should fire after the order is placed and create the the account with the data from the order and the password the customer filled in.

Comment: Thank you for this. Actually, I need to register a customer before the order gets placed. So I need a button "Register" which will display the registration form.

Comment: not sure if this fits your needs, but you can simply add a "Register" button in the checkout  that redirects to the register page and come back to the checkout after the user registers. This looks like the cheapest was to do it